# How to build efficient loops for lookup in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, data.table, data-cleaning

I have a Data set consisting of dates when a person left the network. A person can leave a network multiple times as they may join the network again after leaving it. Following code replicates the scenario.

```
library(data.table)
Leaving_Date<- data.table(Id= c(1,2,3,4,3,5),Date = as.Date(
c("2017-01-01","2017-02-03","2017-01-01","2017-03-10","2017-02-09","2017-02-05")))
```

(ids repeat multiple times in this  table as a person can leave a network multiple times given they joined it again)

```
 > Leaving_Date
   Id       Date
1:  1 2017-01-01
2:  2 2017-02-03
3:  3 2017-01-01
4:  4 2017-03-10
5:  3 2017-02-09
6:  5 2017-02-05
```

I have another dataset giving the dates whenever a particular person was followed up which can be before or after they left the network. Following code replicates the scenario.

```
FOLLOWUPs <- data.table(Id = c(1,2,3,2,2,3,3,4,1,5),
                        Date =as.Date(c("2016-10-01","2017-02-04",
                        "2017-01-17","2017-02-23", "2017-03-03",
                        "2017-02-10","2017-02-11","2017-01-01",
                        "2017-01-15","2017-01-01")))


> FOLLOWUPs
    Id       Date
 1:  1 2016-10-01
 2:  2 2017-02-04
 3:  3 2017-01-17
 4:  2 2017-02-23
 5:  2 2017-03-03
 6:  3 2017-02-10
 7:  3 2017-02-11
 8:  4 2017-01-01
 9:  1 2017-01-15
10:  5 2017-01-01
```

Now I want to lookup each case in Leaving_Date and find dates when they were followed up and create three columns(SevenDay, FourteenDay,ThirtyDay) indicating time period of followup(incase if there was any) in 0s and 1s. I am using following code :

```
SEVENDAY_FOLLOWUP <- vector()
FOURTEEN_FOLLOWUP <- vector()
THIRTYDAY_FOLLOWUP <- vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(Leaving_Date)){
  sub_data <- FOLLOWUPs[Id== Leaving_Date[i,1]]
  if(nrow(sub_data[Date > Leaving_Date[i,Date] &
                   Date < (Leaving_Date[i,Date]+7)])== 0){
     SEVENDAY_FOLLOWUP <- rbind(SEVENDAY_FOLLOWUP,0)
   }
   else{
     SEVENDAY_FOLLOWUP <- rbind(SEVENDAY_FOLLOWUP,1)
   }

   if(nrow(sub_data[Date > Leaving_Date[i,Date] &
                    Date < (Leaving_Date[i,Date]+14)])== 0){
     FOURTEEN_FOLLOWUP <- rbind(FOURTEEN_FOLLOWUP,0)
   }
   else{
     FOURTEEN_FOLLOWUP <- rbind(FOURTEEN_FOLLOWUP,1)
   }

   if(nrow(sub_data[Date > Leaving_Date[i,Date] &
                    Date < (Leaving_Date[i,Date]+30)])== 0){
     THIRTYDAY_FOLLOWUP <- rbind(THIRTYDAY_FOLLOWUP,0)
   }
   else{
     THIRTYDAY_FOLLOWUP <- rbind(THIRTYDAY_FOLLOWUP,1)
   }
 }               


 Leaving_Date$SEVENDAY <- as.vector(SEVENDAY_FOLLOWUP)
 Leaving_Date$FOURTEENDAY <- as.vector(FOURTEEN_FOLLOWUP)
 Leaving_Date$THIRTYDAY <- as.vector(THIRTYDAY_FOLLOWUP)
```

Final Data

```
 > Leaving_Date
    Id       Date SEVENDAY FOURTEENDAY THIRTYDAY
 1:  1 2017-01-01        0           0         1
 2:  2 2017-02-03        1           1         1
 3:  3 2017-01-01        0           0         1
 4:  4 2017-03-10        0           0         0
 5:  3 2017-02-09        1           1         1
 6:  5 2017-02-05        0           0         0
```

This code is very inefficient as I have to run it for 100k observations and it takes a lot of time. Is there any efficient way to do this.

Comment: You might want to read the second circle of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: @Frank I have edited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a non-equi join:

```
setorder(FOLLOWUPs, Id, Date)
Leaving_Date[, n := 
  FOLLOWUPs[.SD, on=.(Id, Date > Date), mult = "first", x.Date - i.Date]
]

   Id       Date       n
1:  1 2017-01-01 14 days
2:  2 2017-02-03  1 days
3:  3 2017-01-01 16 days
4:  4 2017-03-10 NA days
5:  3 2017-02-09  1 days
6:  5 2017-02-05 NA days
```

Switching from `Date` to `IDate` will probably make this about twice as fast. See `?IDate`.

---

I think it's best to stop here, but `n` can be compared against 7, 14, 30 if necessary, like

```
Leaving_Date[, bin := c(7, 14, 30)[ findInterval(n, c(0, 7, 14, 30)) ]]

   Id       Date       n bin
1:  1 2017-01-01 14 days  30
2:  2 2017-02-03  1 days   7
3:  3 2017-01-01 16 days  30
4:  4 2017-03-10 NA days  NA
5:  3 2017-02-09  1 days   7
6:  5 2017-02-05 NA days  NA
```

---

Side note: Please don't give tables names like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you are looking for using `dplyr`.

It does an 'inner join' by Id - generating all combinations of dates in the two data frames for a given Id - then calculates the date differences, groups by Id, then checks whether there are values falling in the ranges for your three categories.

```
library(dplyr)

Leaving_Date2 <- Leaving_Date %>% inner_join(FOLLOWUPs %>% rename(FU_Date=Date)) %>% 
  mutate(datediff=as.numeric(FU_Date-Date)) %>% group_by(Id,Date) %>% 
  summarise(SEVENDAY=as.numeric(any(datediff %in% 0:6)),
            FOURTEENDAY=as.numeric(any(datediff %in% 0:13)),
            THIRTYDAY=as.numeric(any(datediff %in% 0:29)))
```

Comment: If you change your `datediff %in%` statements to be from `0:n` your final result matches the desired one.

Comment: Ah - I see what you are trying to do now!  Amended above. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this as a query instead of a loop.  First, I cleaned your `data.tables` a bit because I was getting confused by the variable names.

To make things easier for the comparison step, we first pre-compute the follow up date  limit for the 7, 14 and 30 day thresholds.

```
library(dplyr)

dt_leaving_neat = Leaving_Date %>%
  mutate(.id = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(limit_07 = Date + 7) %>%
  mutate(limit_14 = Date + 14) %>%
  mutate(limit_30 = Date + 30) %>%
  rename(id = .id, id_person = Id, leaving_date = Date)

dt_follow_neat = FOLLOWUPs %>% 
  select(id_person = Id, followed_up_date = Date)
```

The actual operation is just a query. It's written out in `dplyr` for readability, but if speed is a main concern of yours, you could translate it to `data.table`.  I'd recommend running each step in the pipeline to make sure you understand what's going on.

```
dt_followed_up = dt_leaving_neat %>%
  tidyr::gather(follow_up, limit_date, limit_07:limit_30) %>%
  left_join(dt_follow_neat, by = "id_person") %>%
  mutate(followed_up = (followed_up_date > leaving_date) & (followed_up_date < limit_date)) %>%
  select(id, id_person, leaving_date, follow_up, followed_up) %>%
  filter(followed_up == TRUE) %>%
  unique() %>%
  tidyr::spread(follow_up, followed_up, fill = 0) %>%
  select(id, id_person, leaving_date, limit_07, limit_14, limit_30)
```

The idea is to join the leaving dates to the follow up dates and check whether the follow up date is within the threshold (and also after the leaving date, as presumably you can't follow up before leaving).

Then some final cleaning to return your desired format.  You can use `select` or `rename` to change the column names back too.

```
dt_result = dt_leaving_neat %>%
  select(id, id_person, leaving_date) %>%
  left_join(dt_followed_up, by = c("id", "id_person", "leaving_date"))

dt_result[is.na(dt_result)] = 0
```

Result

```
> dt_result
  id id_person leaving_date limit_07 limit_14 limit_30
1  1         1   2017-01-01        0        0        1
2  2         2   2017-02-03        1        1        1
3  3         3   2017-01-01        0        0        1
4  4         4   2017-03-10        0        0        0
5  5         3   2017-02-09        1        1        1
6  6         5   2017-02-05        0        0        0
```

And following Andrew's answer, an equivalent 1 line `data.table` soln is

```
FOLLOWUPs[Leaving_Date, on = "Id", .(Id, follow_date = Date, leaving_date = i.Date)][, diff := follow_date - leaving_date][, .(seven = any(diff %in% 0:6), fourteen = any(diff %in% 0:13), thirty = any(diff %in% 0:29)), .(Id, leaving_date)]
```